# merging both eclipse for c++ and java in one IDE

Tags: java, android, c++, eclipse, merge

OS : Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I've two versions of eclipse ..

first for c/c++ :

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)
Build id: 20150109-0600

second for java :

Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Luna Service Release 1a (4.4.1)
Build id: 20150109-0600

can I merge both of them into one IDE ??

note that I know that I can do it using :
Help > Install new software ..
but I've extremely slow internet connection and I can't do it .

IF there is no way to do it without using Help > Install new software ..

then I'm forced to do it that way ...

my question then is if I did it using Help > install new software and compressed the whole eclipse folder to use it after re-installing system will I have to do it again ??;

Comment: I've no idea if that works, but have you tried to copy the contents of one folder into the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it just now by copying all contents of eclipse for java folder to eclipse for c/c++ folder .
Important :
DO NOT OVERRIDE FILES WHEN COPYING .. ONLY MERGE AND SKIP IF FILES EXISTS .